Why is the "where are all the Xs?" argument considered strong when X = "time travelers" but weak when X = "aliens"?
Stephen Hawking was considered wise when he performed an antic where he hosted a party for time travelers and send the invites the next day, reasoning that if there were time travelers, receiving the invite in the future would be no big impediment. The physics community received this as a decisive rebuttal of the central point of time travel.
However, upon reflection, this story becomes weak.
Why? Because by that logic, it is just as stupid to believe in aliens, because the exact same logic would hold. But yet, according to physicists, it is considered within the pale of discussion to talk about as a subject extraterrestrial life, due to other reasons ("how could we be alone in such a vast and spacious universe?")
Therefore, why is the "Where are all the time-travelers?" rebuttal considered strong but the "where are all the aliens?" rebuttal considered weak?

You're comparing apples and oranges here. Aliens couldn't have come to Hawking's time traveler party - not unless the aliens were themselves time travelers from a future Earth. But time travelers on Earth could have, and since Hawking's party is now famous, they likely would have for the notoriety. That's why his party is good evidence against time travelers.

It's about the ease of travel. It's hard for aliens to get around, if they're limited by the rocket equation and the speed of light. So even if we don't see any, that's not terribly strong evidence they aren't there. But nothing is clearly stopping a hypothetical time traveler from future Earth from attending Hawking's party - at least, if their time machine is good enough. Hawking's party does not rule out future time travelers with time machines that can't go very far back.

A bit too short for an answer, but the basic summary is 'Space is big'

Even if some physicists called it a decisive rebuttal, I wouldn't believe that they meant it. There's such a thing as exaggeration for comedy. Calling weak evidence against an extraordinarily weak claim a "decisive rebuttal" sounds like that.

@Cubic Remember to include a citation when you quote Hitchhiker's Guide.

I think this question is doing a lot of work with "considered strong" and "considered weak". I think reasonable minds might differ on how 'decisive' a time travel party might be, or find the lack of aliens a convincing argument for interstellar empires being rare.

One obvious factor is awareness of the destination and its attractiveness. Aliens might not be expected to know of the Earth's existence, and even if they did, what could be the possible motivation for making the unimaginable effort required to get here from vast distances? On the other hand, if Earth dwellers were to invent time travel, going back to an earlier point in time on Earth would be a natural priority. That all said, the popular idea of time travel is complete nonsense anyway.

Who said it was?
On the topic of where are the aliens:
We have yet to find with our telescopes a world that might support carbon-based life which is also close enough to us to allow travelers from there to visit us here in rocket ships.
So the question is not "where are the aliens?" but "where are the aliens with hundred-thousand-year lifespans?"

If there are aliens capable of space travel, there are an infinite number of possible destinations.
If there are people on Earth capable of time travel, there is only one place they can go.

First of all the argument structure of "Taking the absence of evidence as evidence for the absence of something" is not a particularly strong argument. That no time travelers or aliens are present is a necessary, but not a conclusive condition.
If there are no time travelers you'd not expect time travelers to attend the party (check). But just because there are no time travelers at the party, doesn't mean that time travelers don't exist.
Like they could simply have better things to do, (idk Hitler, climate change, whatever bullshit we fuck up right now?) and even if the future is all bleak and the time travelers decide to hop into their device to get nostalgically wasted, why on earth would they attend a party that was famously a flop, by someone who by their standards might be a drooling neanderthal (no offense to Mr. Hawking, just the assumption that we likely evolved in our understanding of how the world works to and after developing time travel to a level where he couldn't follow). Also with all these scifi considerations of granpa paradox, would it even be a good idea to tell the old people "hey time travel exists"? Or would it become a meme for time travelers to covertly attend the party as the people who set it up, supply the nibbles and balloons?
There's plenty of good reason for theoretically existing time travelers to not attend that party or not be recognized attending the party.
Apparently it's more of a semi-serious joke. So if things would have worked out he would need to have expected a flashmob of seemingly random people flocking to the Gonville and Caius College at Cambridge University, so not sure how likely it would be to be able to enter that, like even if time travel somehow worked a 1 pound entry fee and a disgruntled guard could be real obstacles. Though that place apparently is free for visitors, but not sure you get there in the first place. Also the GPS coordinates and time might not be sufficient information to find the place given that the "absolute coordinates" of where planet earth is in the future will be vastly different.
Also he is in control of the experiment, like he could do that 365 days a year and pick the one day no one attended and send out the invites AFTER the fact that no one attended. So he can fit the experiment to the result rather than the other way around.
So in essence he had nothing to lose with that, either it would have been a very interesting evening or he had a funny hook to promote his paper on why time travel is actually very unlikely.
So TL;DR that kind of argument was never strong to begin.
Also beware of just semantically changing words and thinking it would preserve the nature of the argument. There are logical structures for which that can work, but it's usually not stable to the level of singular words.

The real trick would be if time travellers attend the party, and then he decides not to publish the invite the next day.
